# How Many People Have Mortgages in Canada?

Tags: econometrics

I found this useful website over here that shows interesting information on income related statistics in Canada (2016) for each postal code:

https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/page.cfm?Lang=E&Geo1=FSA&Code1=V5Y&Geo2=PR&Code2=01&Data=Count&SearchText=V5Y&SearchType=Begins&SearchPR=01&B1=All

As an example, I wanted to see what percentage of people within this area of Vancouver (V5Y) have a mortgage (e.g. Ctrl + F =  " Total - Owner households in non-farm, non-reserve private dwellings - 25% sample data ").

Based on this information -  it appears that in this area of Vancouver, 57.6 % of people have a mortgage.

I had the following question about this:

- It says that this number is based on " 25% sample data."
- **So does this mean that they took a random sample of 25% of all homeowners in this area - and 57.6% of this random sample reported to have a mortgage?**

Can someone please confirm this?

Thanks!